# Implement PBEWithHmacSHA256AndAES_256 with openSSL 1.1.1 and/or Windows crypt functions

Tags: encryption, windows, linux, openssl, java

I have an implementation of password based encryption in Java. It formerly used PBEWithMD5AndDES and was later changed to use PBEWithHmacSHA256AndAES_256. The significant code looks like this:

```
//String cipherAlgorithm = "PBEWithMD5AndDES";
String cipherAlgorithm = "PBEWithHmacSHA256AndAES_256";

PBEKeySpec pbeKeySpec = new PBEKeySpec(passPhrase, salt, iterationCount);
SecretKey secretKey = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance(cipherAlgorithm).generateSecret(pbeKeySpec);

AlgorithmParameterSpec paramSpec = iv == null ?
        new PBEParameterSpec(data.salt, iterationCount) :
        new PBEParameterSpec(data.salt, iterationCount, new IvParameterSpec(iv));

cipher = Cipher.getInstance(cipherAlgorithm);

if (encrypt) {
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey, paramSpec);
} else {
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey, paramSpec);
}

...

byte[] enc = cipher.doFinal(utf8);
```

I have also an implementation with openSSL (and with Windows crypt functions) for the old algorithm. Now I try to extend this to the new algorithm.

The old code using the openSSL implementation looks like this:

```
unsigned char iv[8];
unsigned char key[8];
memset(iv, '\0', sizeof(iv));
memset(key, '\0', sizeof(key));
int rc = EVP_BytesToKey(EVP_des_cbc(), EVP_md5(),
                        salt,
                        apasswd, alen, iterationCount,
                        key, iv);
if (rc != sizeof(key))
    throw ...

EVP_CIPHER_CTX *ectx;
ectx = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new();

EVP_CIPHER_CTX_init(ectx);

if (!EVP_CipherInit_ex(ectx, EVP_des_cbc(), NULL, key, iv, encrypt ? 1 : 0))
    throw ...

if (!EVP_CipherUpdate(ectx, ebuf, &ebuflen, (unsigned char *)abuf, abuflen))
    throw ...

if (ebuflen > (int)abufsize)
    throw ...

...

if (!EVP_CipherFinal_ex(ectx, ebuf, &ebuflen))
    throw ...

...

EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(ectx);
```

I was not successful to get this working. I tried already the following:

1. Replace EVP_des_cbc() with EVP_aes_256_cbc() and EVP_md5() : EVP_sha256()
2. Use PKCS5_PBKDF2_HMAC instead of EVP_BytesToKey (with iv and key sizes adapted to 16 and32)

   PKCS5_PBKDF2_HMAC(apasswd, alen, salt, sizeof(salt),
   iterationCount, EVP_sha256(),
   sizeof(key), key);

But the decryption of data encrypted with the Java implementation fails (EVP_CipherFinal_ex returns an error, so the key seems wrong).

Unfortunately I did not find any information about how PBEWithHmacSHA256AndAES_256 is implemented in Java.

Could anyone point me to more information about this or has anyone successfully implemented similar things (with openSSL or Windows API) and have some hints about this?

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it working, so I can answer the question myself now.

For openSSL, the key can be generated from the passphrase with:

```
int rc = PKCS5_PBKDF2_HMAC((const char *)passPhrase, pLen, salt,
                           sizeof(salt), iterationCount, EVP_sha256(),
                           sizeof(key), key);
```

For Windows, the key can be generated with:

```
    NTSTATUS status;
    BYTE key[32];

    BCRYPT_ALG_HANDLE handle;
    status = BCryptOpenAlgorithmProvider(&handle,
                 BCRYPT_SHA256_ALGORITHM, NULL,
                 BCRYPT_ALG_HANDLE_HMAC_FLAG);

    status = BCryptDeriveKeyPBKDF2(handle, (BYTE*)passPhrase, sizeof(passPhrase),
                 salt, sizeof(salt), iterationCount, key, 32, 0);
```